# When jumping, the rotation value becomes 0

Tags: unity-game-engine

this is my PlayerMovement script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float Speed = 10f;

    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpPower = 3.5f;
    public float directionY;
    bool isGrounded;

    public Animator anim;

    public Transform cam;


    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                directionY = jumpPower;
            }
            else
            {
                directionY = 0;
            }
        }
        if (!controller.isGrounded)
        {
            directionY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        moveDirection.y = directionY;


        if (moveDirection.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

            controller.Move(moveDirection * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        bool hasHorizontalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(horizontal, 0f);
        bool hasVerticalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(vertical, 0f);
        bool isWalking = hasHorizontalInput || hasVerticalInput;

        

    }


}
```

I want to make smooth jump system using by characterController.
My code works fine in the ground state, but when I press space(for jump), it returns the current rotation y value to 0.
(I think this problem is because the jump's position value is y, but the movement's rotation value is also y.)
how do i solve it? I want the rotation value not to change even if I jump.

Comment: Can I suggest changing your `if (moveDirection.magnitude >= 0.1f)` to `if (sqrt(moveDirection.x^2 * moveDirection.y^2) >= 0.1f)`? I feel that the much greater magnitude supplied by your jump power may be influencing this if statement, although may also be completely wrong!

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the code logic. You normalize the vector, then "force" a non-normalized value for the Y axis, then check the magnitude? Also keep in mind if in the next frame the character is grounded, but you release the space bar, the Y is 0. That `else` in the grounded/space bar check might not be reliable if the physics don't apply the next frame. Please try this: keep the space bar pressed at least one more second after the character is in the air and see if the rotation "works" as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.
It was a code execution order issue.

```
float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

    if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        movingDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
    }

    movingDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(movingDirection * Time.deltaTime * speed);


    if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
        controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```